# Ajax get/post on same method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a server method from my controller using ajax `Get` method, in which i have provided data. 
Method accepts arguments does some work and returning a list. I want to use same method for post.

I am getting undefined error when i try to do this.

My Get method looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        traditional:true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Graphs/chartData",
        data: { id: 0, WeatherAll: 0, paramSites: 0 },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
        },
        failure: function (r) {

            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
});
```

My Post method has some google charts like this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            title: 'Humidity/Temperature Measure',
        };
        var idSite = $('#DDLSites').val();
        var idWeatherALL = $('#DDLParameterWeatherAll').val();
        var idParamSites = $('#DDLParameterWeatherSites').val();
        $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Graphs/chartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r);
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);
                var options = {
                    title: 'Humidity/Temperature Measure for Site 1',
                    'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Temperature/Humidity',
                    },
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Time',
                    },
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {

                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

My ChartData Method is:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public JsonResult chartData(int id, int WeatherAll,int  paramSites)
{
    string ids = Convert.ToString(id) + Convert.ToString(WeatherAll) + Convert.ToString(paramSites);
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
    chartData.Add(new object[]
    {
        "Date Time", "Temp", "Humidity"
    });
        ////Some Code here
    return Json(chartData);
}
```

I am unable to figure out how i can do it. Please let me know of any way that is convenient. Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you get `undefined` error?

Comment: Both on Get and Post in ajax calls

Comment: Okay, I can rephrase: there are 72 lines of code in question. Which line (or lines) does throw exception?

Comment: @Regent in both methods i am getting issue with `error: function(r)`

Comment: Have you checked what Ajax error is? There is information about passed to `error` parameters In [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For example, I don't know what it is the point to alert strange (most probably not existing) property `d` of `r` (which is `jqXHR` object).

Comment: For the GET method you have to set **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet** in your controller

return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

And remove the **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",** on the GET Ajax Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes my solution, I created sample Action with AJAX Calls.

**Let Controller Action be -**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Data(int id, string s)
{
    return Json("Test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**let the buttons in HTML be -**

```
<input type="button" value="GET" id="get" />
<input type="button" value="POST" id="post" />
```

**JQuery code to make the AJAX POST and GET -**

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#get").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                traditional: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/data",
                data: { id: 2, s : 'Test'},
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r);
                },
                failure: function (r) {

                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        });

        $("#post").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                traditional: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/data",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: 4, s: 'Test' }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r);
                },
                failure: function (r) {

                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

**Make sure proper Route Config entry is present -**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{s}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, s = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When you make the AJAX GET -

[image]

When you make the AJAX POST -

[image]

Comment: i am getting 'Internal Server Error' with Post ajax call. BTW Get call is success and shows data

Comment: You are getting error with my implementation? Between, you tried to do `JSON.Stringify()`?

Answer (score 1):

For the GET method you have to set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

in your controller

```
return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult chartData(int id, int WeatherAll,int  paramSites)
{
    string ids = Convert.ToString(id) + Convert.ToString(WeatherAll) + Convert.ToString(paramSites);
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
    chartData.Add(new object[]
    {
        "Date Time", "Temp", "Humidity"
    });
        ////Some Code here
    return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, on the GET Ajax Method, as the Data sent to the server is not JsonString.
**GET Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        traditional:true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Graphs/chartData",
        data: { id: 0, WeatherAll: 0, paramSites: 0 },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
        },
        failure: function (r) {

            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
});
```

**POST Ajax**

```
    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Graphs/chartData",
        data: JSON.stringify({id: 0, WeatherAll: 0, paramSites: 0 }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);
            var options = {
                title: 'Humidity/Temperature Measure for Site 1',
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Temperature/Humidity',
                },
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Time',
                },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($("#chart")[0]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {

            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
```